# Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: matlab, classification, signal-processing, speech-recognition, naivebayes

So I am building an Auto Speech Recognition System, and I want to use the *Bayes Theorem* as a classifier.
I am still reading about it and am trying to understand it's concepts, so try to answer me in the simplest way possible.

I have used `MFCC` to Extract the features from my speech and created my `Class_template`, which is an array that contains the rows as features of the word and the columns represent each word(I am only using a ten word vocab,so ten columns are ten words).
Now I have my array of features, and I input a new test word; do the works on it and convert it to a feature vector, and it's all fine.

I want to use Bayes theorem to determine which class(word), in my `class_template` does my new test word belong to.

so I started of by calculating the mean, and standard deviation of each word(both my test word and the class), and now think I am supposed to plug these values in a PDF(prob. density function), and use it to calculate the probability of my test word to each word in my `class_template`, the highest prob. is the right answer I guess.

1-So what am i doing wrong and i am going in the right direction???

2-any tips, pointers, or what to do???

3-when I am calculating the PDF which mean and std should I plug in, the class's or my test word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you described so far is mostly right, but how about the prior probability of the pattern class? if you assume it to be a uniform distribution, then it's the same with MLE and will have bad performance over small sample.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get what you said there?
what is MLE??

Comment: maximum likelihood estmation

Comment: i think u are doing isolated word recognition, and you should plug in the mean and var of the class, consisting of some samples of the same word.

Comment: yes, this exactly what i am doing an ASR for isolated words, and I just don't know what the next step is???

Comment: you should assume a prior probability over words(pattern class), that's like P(word1)=0.02, P(word2)=0.02, then you can compute P(word-n|test word)=P(word-n)*P(test word|word-n), by comparing P(word-n|test word), you can decide which word the test word is. The prior probability is something you should make an assumption.

Comment: estimate P(test word|word-n) needs the pdf you mentioned. There are tricks to select the prior probability distribution, but you can assume it to be uniform distribution also. there should be many code exmaples on mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/

Comment: Thank you man this is really helpful.
a question:
isn't the Bayes equation like this: P(word-n|test word)=(P(word-n)*P(test word|word-n))/p(test word)?
What is p(test word)?
and since i have ten words only p(word-n)=0.1 right?

Comment: yes, because p(test word) is a same denominator for the computation of all probability p(word-n|test), so this value will not affect the result. p(word-n)=0.1 is okay, but if you find it performing not well, you can reassign, like p(word-1)=0.2, p(word-2)=0.5, p(word-3)=0.5.

Comment: OK, so I don't need to p(test word), and p(word-n) can be any number that suites the best performance.

one last thing sir: when I am computing p(test word|word-n), I have my test word vector and the feature vector of the first word, and I want to enter them in the PDF , and since I am using short-term analysis the vector will be cut down to frames.

so i enter the first frame and the corresponding mean and var of the first frame of my class word right?

Comment: yes, it's right. since the p(word-n|test word) is usually small ,you'd better use log(p(word-n|test word)).